# Broken RAID Array, no superblock detected

Tags: centos, raid, mdadm

I run a CentOS system with 2x SSD in RAID1 and 4X SAS drives in RAID10. Linux is installed on the RAID1 array.

This morning I noticed that my RAID10 array (md4) had gone missing, and that my RAID1 array (m2/m3) was broken. I ran a `smartctl` on all the drives, and they all report to be OK.

I checked the raid array:

```
[root@m1 etc]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [multipath] [faulty]
md4 : inactive sdh1[2](S) sdg1[3](S) sdf1[1](S) sde1[0](S)
      46875008958 blocks super 1.2

md3 : active raid1 sdb3[1]
      447318976 blocks [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 2/4 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active raid1 sdb2[1]
      20478912 blocks [2/1] [_U]

unused devices: <none>
```

Both md2 and md3 are not in good shape it seems, and my md127 is now called m4 somehow, and is set to inactive.

Many folders on the filesystem I cannot access anymore, such as /home and /etc, but there are many more. When reading out such a directory I get this error:

```
[root@m1 etc]# dir
-bash: /usr/bin/dir: Input/output error
```

Inspecting md3 shows:

```
[root@m1 etc]# mdadm --detail /dev/md3
/dev/md3:
           Version : 0.90
     Creation Time : Mon Oct  7 10:46:06 2019
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 447318976 (426.60 GiB 458.05 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 447318976 (426.60 GiB 458.05 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
   Preferred Minor : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Mon Oct 21 01:59:57 2019
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       19        1      active sync
```

But using `examine` shows:

```
[root@m1 etc]# mdadm --examine /dev/md3
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/md3.
```

Because /etc for example is not accessible, many important system files cannot be accessed, which is maybe why my md127 array is also gone missing. I think the first step should be fixing md2/md3. As it's RAID1, data should be in intact on at least 1 of the 2 drives I think.

How can I restore those `md2` and `md3` raid arrays so I get my data back?